# Downloading song programmatically from iTunes cloud to local device

Tags: ios, iphone, cloud, mpmediaitem

Is it somehow possible to download a cloudsong programmatically to the applications local bundle? (A `MPMediaItem` that returns true for `MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem`)

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue. As of now not sure if Apple has provided any API to trigger the download.

Best option is to prompt your users to download these cloud items from default apps. e:g Ask them to download the purchased songs from iPhone default music app.